# MySQL - Consulta usando Between para saber se item está reservado na data/hora

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se o item está reservado em uma data X no meu BD. Por exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte banco:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quero reservar o item com resId = 5 na data de 26/02/2019 das 14h30 as 16h30. Mas como ele está reservado das 14h00 as 16h00, não poderia cadastrar a reserva.

Estou tentando usar BETWEEN, mas retorna em branco a query. Mas deveria retornar o id 19, já que existe uma reserva entre essas datas.

```
SELECT * FROM intranet_reuniao 
WHERE resId = 5 
AND (reuDataInicio BETWEEN '2019-02-26 14:30:00' AND '2019-02-26 16:30:00')
```

Qual a lógica que deve ser usada nesse caso?

Comment: acredito que retorne em branco porque ele está pegando a partir das 14h30, e esse horario não tem nenhum registro.

Answer (score 1):

Não basta você acrescentar a cláusula `OR`? Ficando desta maneira:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM intranet_reuniao 
 WHERE resId = 5 
   AND ((reuDataInicio BETWEEN '2019-02-26 14:30:00' AND '2019-02-26 16:30:00')OR
        (reuDataTermino BETWEEN '2019-02-26 14:30:00' AND '2019-02-26 16:30:00'))
```

Logo, se retornar algum registro é porque já existe uma reserva com início ou fim entre as datas de Início e Término.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM intranet_reuniao 
  WHERE resId = 5 
  AND '2019-02-26 14:30:00' > reuDataInicio AND reuDataTermino > '2019-02-26 14:30:00';
```

Não cheguei a testar se o valor antes do > funcionaria, mas a lógica seria isso se a tua data que esta tentando marcar for maior que a de  inicio do que já está, e se a que está agendada acabar depois da que tu quer agendar, não podera.

Comment: Gabriella, obrigado pela ideia, mas não acredito que sua solução seja correta, pois em nenhum momento você informou a data de término da reserva.

Comment: a minha logica foi que se só importa a data de inicio, pois tu ve se a de inicio pode ser e ve se ela não influencia em nenhum termino, porque se isso não influenciar, pode ser adicionado.

Answer (score 0):

Entendo que quer conferir se há alguma reserva no horário especificado. Há **4 hipóteses** para tal condição ser verdadeira.

1. Existe uma reserva que antecede a *data inicio* da especificação e precede a *data fim* da especificação, ou seja, **além** das especificações.
2. Existe uma reserva que precede a *data inicio* da especificação e antecede a *data fim* da especificação, ou seja, **entre** das especificações.
3. Existe uma reserva que antecede a *data inicio* da especificação e precede a *data inicio* da especificação, ou seja, **termina** entre a especificação.
4. Existe uma reserva que antecede a *data fim* da especificação e precede a *data fim* da especificação, ou seja, **começa** entre a especificação.

Visto isso o `where` condition ficaria da seguinte maneira (entre outras tantas):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM intranet_reuniao 
    WHERE resId = 5 
      AND (  (    reuDataInicio >= '2019-02-26 14:30:00' 
              AND reuDataInicio <= '2019-02-26 16:30:00')
           OR
             (    reuDataTermino >= '2019-02-26 14:30:00' 
              AND reuDataTermino <= '2019-02-26 16:30:00')
           OR
             (     reuDataInicio <= '2019-02-26 14:30:00' 
              AND reuDataTermino >= '2019-02-26 16:30:00')         
          )
;
```

Desta forma, a especificação que tem *valor inicio* **antes** da *reuDataInicio* e *valor fim* **além** da *reuDataInicio*, se encaixa na condição 1 e 3 da lista acima. A outra condição é que se a especificação tem *valor inicio* **antes** da *reuDataTermino* e *valor fim* **além** da *reuDataTermino*, se encaixa na condição 1 e 4 da lista acima. A última condição é referente a condição 2 da lista acima.

Isso irá trazer as reservas que há entre o horário especificado.